# assembly rectangles in a box

Tags: optimization, constraints, rectangles, constraint-programming

I have a big rectangular box and many different rectangles to be placed inside.
which mathematical approach could be adopted? 2 dimensions problem

thank you
Paolo

Comment: Can you give us more details on the problem? The way it is currently phrased is too broad.

Comment: This is often called something like `2d rectangular packing`.